# How to return value outside subscribe Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient, angular-http, angular-http-interceptors

**Template**

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let otc of this.jsonData;index as j">
        <div>
            <table class="table table-striped table-fixed">
             
    <tr *ngFor="let opc of this.winServiceInfo(j);index as i">
```

**Typescript**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.geWinService();
  }

 
 winServiceInfo(j: number) {
    this.winServiceURL = JSON.parse(this.WinService[j].windowsServicesInfo)["Stactuscheck"];
    this.dataArrs = [];
    this.service.getWinServicesInfo(this.winServiceURL)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
      )
      .subscribe(
        (data: any) => {
          this.setSubscribeData(data);
          console.log(this.dataArrs);
          return this.dataArrs;
        });
    console.log(this.dataArrs);
    return this.dataArrs;
  }

setSubscribeData(data): any {
    this.WinService = data.windowsServicesInfo;
    this.dataArrs = this.getKeyValJsonObj();
    return this.dataArrs;
  }

getKeyValJsonObj() {
    this.dataArr = [];
    for (let key of this.sliceIntoChunks()) {
      for (let i in key) {
        this.dataArr.push({ 'key': i, 'value': key[i] });
      }
    }
    return this.dataArr;
  }
```

On method winServiceInfo first console.log(this.dataArrs) retuens Arrar(3) but the second console.log(this.dataArrs) returns Arrar(0). I understand that subscribe is an asynchronous operation and for that reason.

So how to handle the situation to return the Array(3) from second console.log(this.dataArrs)

Comment: Why don't you pass the data to the method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, NEVER use a function call like this in HTML.

At every change detection, the function will be ran. Not only this is a huge performance issue, but if you also make HTTP calls, you can ruin someone's data plan in seconds.

Second, try to avoid using `this` like you do. Constrain your variables to the scope of where they're used.

Instead, make an observable to observe :

```js
data$ = forkJoin(
  this.jsonData.map(j => {
    const winServiceURL = JSON
      .parse(this.WinService[j].windowsServicesInfo)["Stactuscheck"];

    return this.service.getWinServicesInfo(this.winServiceURL);
  }).pipe(
    switchMap(data => {
      const WinService = data.windowsServicesInfo;
      const dataArr = [];
      for (let key of this.sliceIntoChunks()) {
        for (let i in key) {
          dataArr.push({ 'key': i, 'value': key[i] });
        }
      }
      return dataArr;
    })
  )
)
```

In your HTML

```html
<div class="row" *ngFor="let opc of data$ | async">
  {{ opc | json }}
</div>
```

Comment: Getting an error Property 'jsonData' is used before its initialization.ts(2729)

Comment: I can't resolve that for you with the code you have provided unfortunately.

Comment: Cool, if it helped, be sure to mark your issue as resolved !